# How to switch both AC and DC voltage to a load

Tags: switches, ac, dc, load

I have a load, an electrode basically acting as a very tiny capacitance, that I want to supply a voltage or bring to ground. The voltage can be either DC, up to about mains voltage, or AC into low KHz frequencies. I'm trying to switch this voltage supply on or off digitally using a microcontroller.

What components or circuit will let me do all of this? I don't believe I can use normal relays, because there is going to be more than one electrode, the footprint of the circuit has to be rather small, and the electrodes will be switched rather frequently. I just recently learned about a number of devices that will only help me switch either AC or DC but are not capable of both, so I'm looking for any tools or techniques I'm not aware of yet.

Edit: As for the electrode current, if the switch is DPST between the hot line and ground, then I expect it to be 1 mA or less, since the electrode is basically a capacitor on the order of 10 pF with a very large resistance. If the electrode cannot directly be grounded by the switch, then it needs some way to bleed off any charge, so another medium resistor *might* need to be added to accomplish this and the current would be slightly higher. The purpose of the electrode is just to bring the surface just above the electrode + a dielectric layer to a given voltage, there will never be real current draw.

The switching rate might be something like 0.5 Hz sustained for half a minute, or it might be even more for a longer period, but I can't be absolutely sure.

Comment: I think you describing something like a SSR, solid state relay. But the drawback is they are expensive. And size is not a problem for SMD surface mountable relays.

Comment: @Nick What is the drive current for the electrode? Also, what is the switching rate envisaged as "rather frequently"?

Comment: The electrode is a "tiny capacitance". This triggers warning bells ... we may have an interesting problem and I think we need to know more... some proposed answers will leave you with much larger capacitances in parallel with it, and inductively coupled switching signals onto it - are these going to be a problem? Are we sensing tiny currents with this electrode?

Comment: Are you measuring the capacitance or voltage on the electrode?  Will series resistance screw your measurement?  Parallel capacitance?

Answer (score 4):

A "*normal*" relay (mechanical or solid state), as mentioned in the question, can definitely be used for switching both AC and DC supplies. What you need to look out for is the **different contact ratings** that a mechanical relay or switch will have for AC voltage and current, DC voltage and current, and reactive AC voltage and current. This last is typically applicable to inductive / electromagnetic coil loads, and should not be of any relevance for the "tiny capacitance" of your electrode. [This answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/53314/14004) provides additional detail.

Something like the [RR2KP series](http://www.rlocman.ru/i/File/dat/IDEC/Power_General_Purpose/RR2KP_UAC120V.pdf) power relays may suit the requirements:
[image: RR2KP mechanical relay]

However, for frequent switching, **mechanical relays are not recommended** both due to mechanical noise, and due to short operational life in terms of number of actuations.

Preferably, a **Solid State Relay** (SSR) rated for the DC and AC voltages and currents envisaged, can be used as well. SSRs are a lot more forgiving about difference between AC and DC ratings. Rating for DC voltage, and AC **peak** voltage, are often the same on SSRs.

Also, SSRs do not typically have contact resistance increasing over time, as there are no actual metal contacts that can degrade through pitting, oxidation et cetera.

For example, the [Omron G3VM-352C/F SSR](http://www.alliedelec.com/images/products/datasheets/bm/OMRON_ELECTRONICS_LLC/70175578.pdf) may meet the requirements:
[image: Omron G3VM SSR]

SSRs are typically rated for many more actuations than a mechanical relay. This would fit in with the requirement for *switching rather frequently*.

SSRs are available in really tiny surface mounted packages, so the *size constraint* mentioned is also addressed.

[image: SMD SSRs]

SSRs are typically **much more expensive** than typical mechanical relays, though.

If the various supply voltages mentioned are fed in through a single connection ("hot" and neutral / ground), then a simple SPST relay (mechanical or SSR) can be used, if it meets the following criteria:

- Actuation voltage and current are within the capability of your microcontroller circuit, or an added driving element, e.g. MOSFET switch, is incorporated in the circuit.
- Both the DC and AC supplies are within the respective ratings of the relay contacts.
- The relay datasheet actually specified both AC and DC operation / ratings. Don't assume a relay is good for DC if not specified, for instance.

If, however, (and this isn't clear to me from the question) the DC and AC supplies are fed in on different connections, then a DPST (Double Pole Single Throw) relay would be needed... though some high voltage industrial applications use two separate relays for such purpose, if only to provide greater physical isolation between the two lines and prevent inter-circuit arcing during turn-off.

Comment: what the hell is inter-circuit arching?

Comment: @sandundhammika Arc formation between the two circuits / connections on a Double Pole relay, when one of the contacts is disconnected - Basically a spark from the high potential lead of the circuit being opened, to the low potential lead of the second circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Another type of relay for low currents and small size is a Reed relay.  Only SPST though but they are tiny.  You can get shielded version to allow you to put multiple side by side.
There are (larger ones) that can switch 10 KV, which surprised me.  Low voltage ones are even SMT.